# Flat shading OpenGL using Three.js

Tags: three.js, flat

I am trying to simulate the OpenGL flat shading model using Three.js. My idea is creating an example like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phong-shading-sample.jpg. I was trying to change some different shading models but I cannot obtain the desired result.

Is it possible to create this scene in three.js?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One way to get around this, would be to use models exported from Blender, as it is capable of exporting as either flat or smooth shaded.

Answer (score 2):

Materials e.g. the MeshBasicMaterial have an option called "shading". It can be set to THREE.None, THREE.FlatShading, THREE.SmoothShading.

I am not sure if you need a light source in the first place or wether you have to enable shading for a the whole scene. Look at the demos at the Three.js website for something with shading.